# AFNetworking only alerts for Network unreachable -> Network reachable transition

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking 2.4.1 and tested it only on the iPad simulator.
What I'm doing is trying to add an handler for network transition (from reachable to unreachable and vice versa):

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus){
    bool networkAvailable = [AFNetworkReachabilityMananger sharedManager].reachable;
    NSLog(networkAvailable ? @"Network is on" : @"Network is off");
}];
```

Anyone else had the same problem?

Comment: What is you problem?

Comment: @trick14 That it only executes the block on network off -> network on transition

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
        default:
    }    
}];
```